# Get the number string from a char variable and re-assign it to a integer variable

Tags: c, string, ascii

Here i have a char type variable which holds a number value as string say 21,I want to assign 21 to a integer variable.I did the following thing but it prints -12.why it is printing -12 and how i can get 21 in my int variable?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
char character = "21";
int x = (int)character - '0';
printf("%d",x);
}
```

Comment: It is invalid code to put `char character = "21";`. The data is a *string literal* which should be assigned to a `char` array like `char character[] = "21";`

Comment: Also note that `char *character = "21";` is a valid alternative.

Comment: With the code `int x = (int)character - '0';` this would work, but only for a *single digit* such as `char character = '7';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "sscanf".

```
int main(){
char *character = "21";
int x = 0;

sscanf(character, "%d", &x);
printf("%d",x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to convert from a string to an integer is to use the `atoi()` or `sscanf()` functions.